# Closed form for sum of constant to the power of a quadratic polynomial in the index variable.

Tags: summation

> How do I find a closed form solution of the following sum?
>   $$\sigma=\sum_{i=1}^n \gamma^{\alpha i^2 + \beta i}=\sum_{i=1}^n \gamma^{\alpha i^2}\gamma^{\beta i}$$

**My attempt:**

I tried using the method which would solve $\sum\gamma^{\alpha i}$ where I would do this:

$$
\begin{aligned} \sigma =&\, \gamma^{\alpha} + \gamma^{2\alpha} + \dots + \gamma^{n\alpha} \\
\gamma^\alpha \sigma =& \hspace{2.675em} \gamma^{2\alpha} + \dots + \gamma^{n\alpha} + \gamma^{(n+1)\alpha}
\end{aligned}
$$

However there isn't a factor which does the same trick because of the $i^2$. Is there a different method for solving this, or is there no closed form solution?

Comment: By definition, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a^{n^2}=\theta_3(0,a)$, and $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a^{n^2+n+\frac14}=\theta_2(0,a).~$ See [$\theta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "closed form" for this sum due to the $i^2$ term.

Comment: Can you prove this statement?

Comment: OK. There is no known closed form. I don't think it's possible to prove that we will never know for sure. There may be some deep connection between $\pi$ and $e$ but we don't know.

Comment: Mathematica and Maple fail to find one, even if $\beta$ is zero, which is enough proof for me.